# Append Model to VXYModelMapper

Tags: qt, qml, qstandarditemmodel

I use "VXYModelMapper" and "QStandardItemModel" in plot chart. I use blow codes but append model to VXYModelMapper is very slow.

```
VXYModelMapper {
        model: myChartClass.newMyChartModel
        series: lineSeries
        xColumn: 0
        yColumn: 1
}
void MyChartClass::setMyChartModel(QStandardItemModel *model)
{
  newMyChartModel= model;
  emit myChartModelChanged(model);
}

QStandardItemModel* lineModel=new QStandardItemModel(npcArray.size(), 2);
foreach(const QJsonValue & val, npcArray){
    double xVal=val.toObject().value("x").toDouble();
    double yVal=val.toObject().value("y").toDouble();

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(xVal));
    lineModel->setItem(i, 0, item1);

    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(yVal));
    lineModel->setItem(i, 1, item2);
     i+=1;
}

 //To this line everything is very good and fast   

QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();
myChartClass->setMyChartModel(lineModel);
qDebug() << "The slow operation took" << timer.elapsed() << "millisecond";
```

> Output: The slow operation took **123045** millisecond. Total point
>   count: **5188**

It is very slow :(

**Update**:
I use QTimer but not benefit. :(

```
lineModel=new QStandardItemModel(0, 2);
myChartClass->setMyChartModel(lineModel);
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(30);


void MyChartClass::update(){

int toIndex=fromIndex+100;
if(toIndex>=npcArray.size()){
    toIndex=npcArray.size()-1;
}

for(int i=fromIndex;i<toIndex;i++){
    double xVal=npcArray[i].toObject().value("x").toDouble();
    double yVal=npcArray[i].toObject().value("y").toDouble();

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(xVal));
    lineModel->setItem(i, 0, item1);

    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem(QString::number(yVal));
    lineModel->setItem(i, 1, item2);
}
fromIndex=toIndex;
}
```

Comment: But why QElapsedTimer shows the delay in the last line?

Comment: version of Qt: Qt 5.11.2

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I consume 123045 milliseconds if I do it after showing the window, if I do it before it consumes 0 millisecond :O. Well, I need the user to select a chart from the list to display it. 
So the code runs after after showing the window.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend. I will try it.

Comment: @eyllanesc
I use QTimer but not benefit :(

Comment: Speed of append row in model will slow down when increasing the number of rows and chart is displayed with large delays.